# Rails - main class, sub class, how to get all records with subclass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, routes, single-table-inheritance

In using STI, I'm trying to get all pages of a specific :type.

I have a main class in pages_controller.rb

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @pages = Page.all
  end

end
```

Below that, I have another class in pages_controller.rb

```
class Blog < Page

    def index
        @pages = Blog.all   
    end

end
```

Shouldn't the Blog class get all pages with a :type of "Blog"? Instead it is getting all pages regardless of the type. I've also tried `@pages = Page.where(:type => "Blog")` I'm accessing the URL http://localhost:3000/blog

Here are my routes

```
    resources :pages do
        collection do
            get :gallery
            get :list
        end     
    end
    resources :blog, :controller => :pages
```

Comment: I think it would be better if you create a separate controller, instead of making a class in the PagesController itself.

Comment: Is that the only way it will work? My fear is, if I have 3 or 4 :types then I would need 3 or 4 controllers. And each controller would contain similar code (e.g. - Getting all pages by type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a class for every type in `app/models` directory:

```
# app/models/page.rb
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
end

# app/models/blog.rb
class Blog < Page
end
```

If you want one controller to get them both:

```
if blog? # implement this method yourself
  @blogs = Blog.all
else
  @pages = Page.all
end
```

So in essence, the `all`-method returns instances of the class you called it on.

However: I would recommend you to use separate controller for each type. They are different resources and should be treaded as such. Use tools like [InheritedResources](https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources) to dry up your controllers.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the heads up on that. It just seemed weird to me to have to define model for every page type and leave it blank. If it works and that's the only way, I'm down with that. -- I now have a separate controller and model for each page type. I think I'm getting errors now because it wants new views for each type (ugh). Is this where InheritedResources comes into play?

Comment: Another quick question. In each controller (Blog, Photo) do I need to create actions for new, create, edit, etc? Seems like I'm slowly but surely duplicating a lot of code (only diff between the controllers is the Page controller has Page.new and the blog controller has Blog.new), is that right?

Comment: That's why I'm recommending InheritedResources. But you can use one controller too. Empty classes are no problem. They're ActiveRecord, so they aren't empty at all.

Comment: InheritedResources allowed me to clean up the initial Pages controller, but not the controller for the other types (Blog, Photo). I also tried inherited resources views for views. What a mess.